# Control de secuencia de Sprites a través de DeltaTime

Tags: c++, algoritmos

Anteriormente en mi bucle principal del juego, el tiempo lo gestionaba a 60 FPS y el respectivo Delay para el retraso del tiempo.

La secuencia de Sprite era animada de la siguiente forma:

```
if(++ciclos > 10){
   siguienteSprite++;
   ciclos = 0;
}
```

Dado a que estoy utilizando Movimiento Suaves con DeltaTime, por consiguiente he eliminado el Delay del Ciclo principal; haciendo esto que los ciclos de sprites de la animación sean más rápido, y no solo esto, sino que también varía el tiempo entre cada secuencia.

Alguien podría darme una mano, sólo con la lógica de este problema, de ante mano gracias.  :)

Comment: No queda claro que estas preguntando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí una solución:

```
t1 = get_actual_time();
while (t1-t0>=animation_T)
{
 siguienteSprite++;
 t0+=animation_T;
}
```

Tomada de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917471/sprites-sequence-control-through-deltatime/41920247#41920247